# Dartlang class VS JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, dart

I've the below JS code using JS classes, that multiple rectangles got generated, in different random locations, 
the static rectangle start moving upon click, and the moving rectangle is destroyed if clicked.

I want to re-write the same code in Dart language, I did not know what shall I use instead of the JS `myRect.prototype` in dart, considering that I prefer not to include all the class properties and functions inside the main `class { }` any idea?

```
var NS="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";     
var SVG=function(h,w){
    var svg=document.createElementNS(NS,"svg");
    svg.width=w;
    svg.height=h;
return svg;
}
var svg=SVG(1200,1500);
document.body.appendChild(svg);

class myRect {
  constructor(x,y,h,w,fill,name) {
   this.name=name;
   this.SVGObj= document.createElementNS(NS,"rect");
   self = this.SVGObj;
      self.x.baseVal.value=x;
      self.y.baseVal.value=y;
      self.width.baseVal.value=w;
      self.height.baseVal.value=h;
      self.style.fill=fill;
      self.addEventListener("click",this,false);
  }
}

Object.defineProperty(myRect.prototype, "draw", {
   get: function() {
      return this.SVGObj;
   }
});

myRect.prototype.handleEvent= function(evt){
self = this.SVGObj;
  switch (evt.type){
    case "click":   
       if (typeof self.moving == 'undefined' || self.moving == false) self.moving = true;
       else self.moving = false;

     if(self.moving == true)
       self.move = setInterval(()=>this.animate(),100);
       else{
       clearInterval(self.move); 
       self.parentNode.removeChild(self);
       }        
    break;
    default:
    break;
 }
}  

myRect.prototype.step = function(x,y) {
   return svg.createSVGTransformFromMatrix(svg.createSVGMatrix().translate(x,y));
}

myRect.prototype.animate = function() {
       self = this.SVGObj;
              self.transform.baseVal.appendItem(this.step(1,1));
};

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var x = Math.random() * 500,
        y = Math.random() * 300;

    var r= new myRect(x,y,10,10,'#'+Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16),'this is my name');
    svg.appendChild(r.draw);
}
```

Comment: Can't you just make a method?

Comment: @Pacane, did not get your point :(

Comment: Make a class, add methods to it.

Comment: @Pacane, this is my question, how to add the method to the class, outside the class detention, I.e. after the `class { }` how can I define the method!

Comment: You can't. What you can do is implement `noSuchMethod` and then handle calls to undefined methods there.

Comment: As Gunter said, you can't. But nothing prevents you from adding methods inside the class, like any other normal class. That's what I'd do for the rewrite of your piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add methods to a class or object dynamically in Dart. Your options are:

1. Put them inside the class
2. Make them functions that take the rectangle as an argument

I would go with (2), just make them functions that accept an instance of your class:

```
handleEvent(myRect, evt){
  // ...
}
```